# Дана строка из слова и перевода. Бот спрашивает слово, а мы должны написать перевод. Но бот не ждет нашего ответа и двигается по коду дальше

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У нас строка, в которой записано слово и через пробел перевод, затем следующее и тд. Этот фрагмент кода - это мини-игра, бот должен отправить в диалоге слово, а нам нужно написать перевод. Но он не ждет нашего ответа и сразу отправляет в ветку else. Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def slovar(message):
   f =  open('read.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') 
   fun = f.readline()
   fun = fun.split()
   while len(fun) != 0:
       sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Переведи слово {word}'.format(word=fun[0]))
       if sent.text == fun[1]:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
       else: 
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не верно! Правильный ответ: {word}'.format(word = fun[1]))
       fun = fun[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны обработку ответа занести в другую функцию с параметром message.И добавить строку перед функцией:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
```

И тогда эта функция будет запускаться, когда пользователь отправит сообщение. Также советую посмотреть вот это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8fhrtvedHA).Там все подробно расписано.